# Xamarin forms - can't scan BLE devices

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I new in Xamarin forms and C#.
I am trying to scan BLE device using the native Xamarin forms API, the code attached. I am using the Xiomi note 5 running android 9.

```
using Android.Bluetooth;
using Android.Bluetooth.LE;
using Android.Runtime;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;


namespace bletest
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]


    public class MyScanCallback : ScanCallback
    {
        public override void OnBatchScanResults(IList<ScanResult> results)
        {
            base.OnBatchScanResults(results);
        }

        public override void OnScanResult([GeneratedEnum] ScanCallbackType callbackType, ScanResult result)
        {
            base.OnScanResult(callbackType, result);
        }

        public override void OnScanFailed([GeneratedEnumAttribute] ScanFailure errorCode)
        {
            base.OnScanFailed(errorCode);
        }
    }

    public class newbtle
    {
        private readonly BluetoothAdapter   _ba;
        private readonly BluetoothLeScanner _sc;
        private readonly MyScanCallback     _scCb;
 
        public newbtle()
        {
            _ba = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
            _sc = _ba.BluetoothLeScanner;
            _scCb = new MyScanCallback();

        }

        public  void BleScan()
        {
            if (_ba.Enable() == true)
            {
                _sc.StartScan(_scCb);
            }
        }

        public void BleScanStop()
        {
            _sc.StopScan(_scCb);
            _sc.FlushPendingScanResults(_scCb);
            _ba.Disable();
        }

        public string GetScanMode()
        {
            return _ba.ScanMode.ToString();
        }

        public string GetStateMode()
        {
            return _ba.State.ToString();
        }

    }



    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        newbtle bt = new newbtle();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bt.BleScan();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bt.BleScanStop();

        }

    }
}
```

When a call is made to bt.BleScan no call back is called, when the bt.BleScan called in the second time without turning the scanner off the OnScanFailed is called with 'already active error'.

When I run the BLE explorer utility on the same mobile in the same environment it scan few BLE devices.

Any suggestion what can be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Just double checking, does your app have all the runtime required perms? Location course & fine and bluetooth admin?

Comment: It has the fine and course location and the Bluetooth permissions.